# redirected url of production on store prestashop

Tags: xampp, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Trying to customize a prestashop store. Unfortunately I have posted the htdos production folder.

When accessing my localhost environment, it is redirected when I try to enter the url of production. Where I can change this behavior to develop on prestashop?

Can you be a web filter?, I tested in the prestashop admin console and I see no configuration.

Nor does this in any config file in the folder

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded the production folder there are some settings that will have to change in the database because they probably don't match for both sites.

Look in table PS_CONFIGURATION and find name PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL -> change those values to match the domain you are working on.

Then go to PS_SHOP_URL -> Also change that domain and domain ssl to match the domain your working on. Then under physical_uri put a / if prestashop is in the root. If Pretashop is under a directory you will have to put the directory name there ex: /prestashop/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this already, struggled a lot and totally I changed the url `above 55 places` in database. I followed easy way,

First, changed the config, `settings.inc` file

Second, export database-> replaced the `local url` with `live url` in the `database.sql` file and `imported` the replaced file into the new location. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To change that you have to go into administration and into Preferences-> SEO and URL

There you change the domain of the store. That will overwrite the htaccess and it will run on localhost. Otherwise, you can disable and then re-enable friendly URL to force overwriting the htaccess.